# ¿Como subir una react-table a firebase?

Tags: firebase, reactjs

Buenas, me gustaria tener alguna pista de como implementar el método set. para llevar los datos de una react-table a firebase.

```
constructor(prosp) {
  super(prosp);
  this.state = {
    ships: [
      {
        article: mesa,
        description: "Lapto",
        route: "DLA-WC",
        users: "Juan",
        progress: 'yes',
        delivered: 'no'
      },
      {
        jobs: [
          {
            users: "", description: "", route: ""
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: se implementaria de la misma forma que se implemente cualquier dato?

Comment: Es igual que cualquier información que desees guardar, lo importante es tener una buena estructura en tu base de datos ya como lo muestres depende de lo que se necesite.